# C++ C4244 =': conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data; any solution?

Tags: c++, class, type-conversion, warnings, private

I'm fairly new to C++ and I just got done learning about Classes. I don't know why I keep getting this error C4244(check title).
I'm using Visual Studio 2017
Feedback would be appreciated.

//my program askes users to enter a sentence 
    `

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
Const short MAX = 132;

class information
{
char sentence[MAX];
short gcount;
public:
    unsigned short CharCount;
    void InputData();
    void showresult();
};
Int main()
{
    Information data;
    data.InputData();
    data.showresult();
    return 0;
}

void information::InputData()//member function to enter info
{
    cin.ignore(10, '\n');
    cout << "Enter your sentence " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin.getline(sentence, sizeof(sentence));
    CharCount = cin.gcount(); // this is the problem

}

void information::showresult() //show number of characters
{
    cout << " Characters in the sentence:: " << CharCount  << endl; 
    system(“Pause”);
}
```

`

Comment: What about it don't you understand?  `short` is smaller than `streamsize` so you could lose data doing that conversion.

Comment: Note - this is not an error, merely a warning. Compiler is trying to tell you "I'm not sure, but this might be incorrect, check it out".

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Warnings which are not understood should be treated like errors: Understand them, fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that you are trying to store a value that might be too large for the container you are trying to put it in. `cin.gcount()` returns a value of type `std::streamsize`. This is typically a signed 64-bit (or 32-bit) number. `CharCount` is an `unsigned short`, which is typically 16-bits.

Effectively, you are trying to store a signed 64-bit value into an unsigned 16-bit value, which the compiler is not happy with. You should change `CharCount` to be of type `std::streamsize` as well.

Or, as suggested by user253751, since you know it'll be a small size (132), you can just cast to an `unsigned short`.

Comment: Or since you know it's shorter than 132 characters, you could simply cast it.

Comment: @user253751 Edited to include that.

Comment: Re: "trying to store a value that is too large" -- no, the warning is that the value **might be** too large. The compiler doesn't know what the actual value is, so cannot give an opinion about whether it will fit.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fixed.

Comment: thanks for the inputs everyone, by type casting, would the format be similar to this "static_cast<TYPE>(Object)" and apply to CharCount?

Comment: @Tamh_Ply, yes, you can cast that way. `static_cast<unsigned short>(cin.gcount())`